# dbext seems to think ( is a sql statement terminator

Tags: sql, vim, dbext

I have this in the .sql file in my buffer:

```
 CREATE TABLE WH.dbo.customer(
        id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
        cust_name       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        phone_nbr       VARCHAR(30) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );
```

If I am in normal mode and the cursor is on `TABLE` then I sould be able to hit either `<Leader>se` or command gVim to `:DBExecSQLUnderCursor` and the statement should be executed as dbext should find `CREATE` and `;` and then execute the script in between. But i get the following message:

```
Last SQL:
CREATE TABLE WHAnalysis.dbo.customer(
```

If I highlight all the script and choose Execute SQL (Visual selection) from the plugin menu then it runs fine.

What is going on? Could it be a setting in my `_vimrc`?:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set diffexpr=MyDiff()

" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
:nnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>
:vnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>gv
:cnoremap <C-S>     <C-C>:update<CR>
:inoremap <C-S>     <C-O>:update<CR>

" Microsoft SQL Server
let g:dbext_default_profile_WH = 'type=SQLSRV:user=dbuser:passwd=dbuserpassword:dsnname=SQLOLEDB.1:srvname=dwdb'

set nocp
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

"Mouse and backspace
set mouse=a

function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>p :pyf P:\Computer Applications\Python\

"quick quit command
noremap <Leader>e :quit<CR> "quits the current window



" Rebind <Leader> key
let mapleader = ","

map <Leader>n <esc>:tabprevious<CR>
map <Leader>m <esc>:tabnext<CR
```

Comment: Does it work when everything is one line? If it does most likely the problem is your function is taking the newline and passing it as part of the query

Comment: Why don't you get in touch with the maintainer?

Comment: @romainl - ok - I'll try mailing David fishburn with a link to this question

Comment: @romainl Great idea - David Fishburn has been very helpful and really took time out to explain some stuff to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke to the plugin maintainer David Fishburn - I was amazed at the time-out he took to help a novice like me: great guy.

Initially he suggested

> I believe the cmd terminator for SQLSRV is "\ngo\n" not ";".
>
> If you want to change it temporarily to try in this buffer run:
>   :DBSetOption cmd_terminator=';'
>
> Try the cmd again.
>
> If that works you can either override the default or change your
>   profile to override it.

Then in answer to some further related questions:

> **Q1. What is "\ngo\n" ?**
>
> Because the string is enclosed in double quotes, Vim treats escaped
>   characters differently. \n - newline go \n - newline
>
> So for SQL Server this would be typical:
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE 
>   BEGIN 
>   END 
>   go
>
> Which is actually:
>   "END\ngo\n"
>
> In other words, "go" has to be on a newline, with only "go" on the
>   line.
>
> **Q2. Do I just add the following to _vimrc for it to become permanent?:**
>
> > DBSetOption cmd_terminator=';'
>
> No. :DBSetOption is used to modify current buffer settings only, not
>   permanent settings.
>
> The best thing you can do is read through :h dbext.txt.
>
> The specific answer to your question lies in :h dbext-configure-options
>
> 5.3 Database Specific Options                   *dbext-configure-options*
>       The command terminator is automatically added to a command before it is
>       sent to the database.  The command options are also added to the command
>       line used to execute the statement. >
>
> ```
>     dbext_default_SQLSRV_bin               = "osql"
>     dbext_default_SQLSRV_cmd_header        = ""
>     dbext_default_SQLSRV_cmd_terminator    = "\ngo\n"
>     dbext_default_SQLSRV_cmd_options       = '-w 10000 -r -b -n'
>     dbext_default_SQLSRV_extra             = ''
> ```
>
> So, to permanently override for all buffers in your .vimrc you would
>   add:
>           let g:dbext_default_SQLSRV_cmd_terminator    = ";"